# como importar dados em formato excel para o matlab

Tags: matlab

Quero importar dados do excel para o matlab, já tentei com o importdata mas há qualquer cosia que não bate certo. Aparece-me «NaN» em vez de números na matriz

Comment: qual código vc tentou?

Answer (score 5):

Já tentou usar o xlsread?

```
xlsread(nome do arquivo,pasta,intervalo)
```

Exemplo:

```
% Criar um arquivo do excel chamado Exemplo.xlsx.

values = {1, 2, 3 ; 4, 5, 'x' ; 7, 8, 9};
headers = {'primeiro','segundo','terceiro'};
xlswrite('Exemplo.xlsx',[headers; values]);

% Pasta tem então os dados (Exemplo.xlsx):

   primeiro    Segundo    Terceiro
       1         2        3
       4         5        x    
       7         8        9

%Ler os dados numéricos da primeira pasta do arquivo:

filename = 'Exemplo.xlsx';
A = xlsread(filename)
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5   NaN
     7     8     9
```

Para mais informações acesse o [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Exporte pelo o excel no formato csv, pode ser separado por vírgula ou espaço

O processo de leitura, necessita apenas em utilizar o `csvread(filename)`

Exemplo de uso: `arq = csvread(arqExcel.csv)`

Fonte: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html