# Como criar uma tabela no MATLAB?

Tags: table, matlab, tabela-html

Estou fazendo um trabalho que quero criar a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei vários comandos como table e readtable e sempre me retorna a seguinte mensagem :

```
Undefined function 'readtable' for input arguments of type 'char'. 
 Undefined function 'table' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Também tentei importar do excel e não deu certo.
Sei que é algo simples, mas eu não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Eu já tentei isso, de readtable, mas dá a mensagem que coloquei acima: Undefined function 'readtable' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: P.S.: Como se pode perceber pelo link postado pelo colega @Marconi, a função `readtable` é bem recente e existe apenas na versão `R2015a`. O meu MATLAB, por exemplo, que está na versão `R2013a` também dá esse erro porque a função não existe.

Comment: Então é isso o meu é o R2013a, por isso tá dando esse erro.

Comment: Eu quero criar essa tabela numa rotina, já fiz a tabela no excel, mas também não consegui importá-la pro Matlab.

Comment: Eu posso criá-la manualmente ou importar do Excel, pra mim tanto faz, desde que ela apareça na rotina, está ótimo.

Comment: Obrigada @Marconi !

Comment: Eu consegui criar uma com o comando disp, mas não aparece os nomes, só os números. Eu quero que ela fique exatamente como na imagem, creio que não seja impossível de fazer, eu só não estou sabendo fazer.

Comment: Vc consegue me ajudar Luiz Vieira?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer de acordo com sua ajuda, espero que dê certo. Foi a primeira vez que perguntei aqui, obrigada pelas dicas, pode deixar que da próxima vez eu facilitarei a pergunta!

Comment: Deu certinho, como vc mostrou! Mas ele não aparece no formato inteiro da tabela né? Muito obrigada mesmo @LuizVieira

Comment: Annie, não porque na verdade essa estrutura de dados não é uma matriz, mas um *cell array* (porque matrizes só podem ter o mesmo tipo de dados, e esse tem string e números). Você pode ter uma visão melhor fazendo `visao = [dados{1} dados{2} dados{3}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você já tem a tabela no Excel, o jeito que talvez seja mais fácil é exportar os dados do Excel para um arquivo [CSV (Comma-Separated Value)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Basta ir no menu "*Arquivo*" e escolher a opção "*Salvar como*". Na janela de diálogo, escolha o tipo do arquivo como CSV:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu Excel é o em português, e por isso ele usa o ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) no lugar da vírgula (`,`) como separador, uma vez que a vírgula em português é usada para separar as decimais em números (o ponto é usado para separar decimais no inglês, por isso não há confusão na leitura do arquivo). O arquivo CSV, pra mim, ficou com esse conteúdo:

```
Componente;Amostra MT(phr);Amostra LN (phr)
Elastrômetro;100;100
Cargas;110;60
Plastificante;34;9
Ativador de vulcanização;4,5;4,5
Auxiliar de fluxo e processo;4,5;4,5
Agente acelerador de vuncanização;5,5;6
```

Depois de ter esse arquivo, você pode importar os dados para uma matriz no MATLAB usando o seguinte código:

```
arquivo = fopen('c:\temp\teste.csv', 'r');
dados = textscan(arquivo,'%s%s%s','delimiter',';')
fclose(arquivo);
```

O que esse código faz é (1) abrir o arquivo para leitura, (2) ler os dados segundo os formatos e delimitador especificados, e (3) fechar o arquivo. Note que eu forcei o delimitador como ponto-e-vírgula, por causa do arquivo exportado pelo meu Excel. Talvez você não precise fazer o mesmo, se o seu Excel for em inglês e exportar separando os dados com vírgula. Note também que eu estou formatando tudo como string (usando `%s` para todas as colunas). O ideal seria importar os valores numéricos convertendo-os apropriadamente para `float`, mas você pode fazer isso posteriormente (ou editar o arquivo pra remover manualmente a linha do cabeçalho, se esses dados não forem importantes).

O resultado é uma matriz com as seguintes colunas e linhas:

```
>> dados

dados = 

    {7x1 cell}    {7x1 cell}    {7x1 cell}
```

E você pode acessar os valores usando a seguinte sintaxe para obter as colunas individualmente:

```
>> dados{1}

ans = 

    'Componente'
    'Elastrômetro'
    'Cargas'
    'Plastificante'
    'Ativador de vulcanização'
    'Auxiliar de fluxo e processo'
    'Agente acelerador de vuncanização'

>> dados{2}

ans = 

    'Amostra MT(phr)'
    '100'
    '110'
    '34'
    '4,5'
    '4,5'
    '5,5'

>> dados{3}

ans = 

    'Amostra LN (phr)'
    '100'
    '60'
    '9'
    '4,5'
    '4,5'
    '6'
```

> P.S.: Há também a função chamada [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), que também existe na
>   versão 2013 (apesar da documentação não deixar muito claro). Ela pode
>   te ajudar, mas é menos flexível na leitura dos arquivos e só lê dados
>   numéricos (ou seja, o seu arquivo não pode ter texto). Outra alternativa é a função `xslread`, já descrita [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67048/como-importar-dados-em-formato-excel-para-o-matlab).

---

### EDIÇÃO:

Apenas para deixar mais completo, coloco aqui uma versão que faz a conversão dos dados numéricos apropriadamente. Lembre-se que eu preciso substituir a vírgula por ponto-e-vírgula porque meus dados foram exportados via um Excel em português. A conversão para número apenas a partir da segunda linha (note o índice `(2:end)` usado para acessar as colunas) se deve para ignorar o cabeçalho e mantê-lo como string.

> A função [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) que eu uso é muito interessante, pois permite
>   usar/chamar outra função (no meu exemplo, a função `str2num`) para
>   cada valor em uma matriz.

Eis o código:

```
arquivo = fopen('c:\temp\teste.csv', 'r');
dados = textscan(arquivo,'%s%s%s','delimiter',';')
fclose(arquivo);

% Conversões:
% Para cada coluna (2 e 3), primeiro substitui a vírgula (,) por ponto (.)
% e então converte para número apenas os dados da segunda linha em diante
% (note o (2:end) na indexação dos dados).
dados{2}(2:end) = strrep(dados{2}(2:end), ',', '.')
dados{2}(2:end) = cellfun(@str2num, dados{2}(2:end), 'UniformOutput', 0)

dados{3}(2:end) = strrep(dados{3}(2:end), ',', '.')
dados{3}(2:end) = cellfun(@str2num, dados{3}(2:end), 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

Que agora resulta em valores devidamente convertidos para números dentro do MATLAB:

```
>> dados{2}

ans = 

    'Amostra MT(phr)'
    [   100]
    [   110]
    [    34]
    [4.5000]
    [4.5000]
    [5.5000]
```